# Is the set $T = \{x\in\mathbb{R}: 2 x^2 \cos(1/x) \le 1 \} \cup \{0\}$ complete?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $T = \{x\in\mathbb{R}: 2 x^2 \cos(1/x) \le 1 \} \cup \{0\}$.  Is this is a complete set in $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to usual metric?

I am thinking about using the fact that the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed, but here $2 x^2 \cos(1/x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$, since it's not defined at $x=0$. On the set $A=[-\infty , 1]$ which is closed , $f(x)$ is not continuous (due to zero). 
On $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;\mathrm{such\;that\;} 2 x^2 \cos(1/x) >1\}$, $2 x^2 \cos(1/x)$ is continuous , and $(1,\infty)$ is an open set so $P$ is an open set. Now the complement of $P$ is $K=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \;\mathrm{such\;that}\; 2x^2 \cos(1/x) \leq 1\}$ is a closed set (?) and $\{0\}$ is a closed set so $T\setminus K \cup\{0\}$ is a closed set. Am I right? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Show that the set is closed .

Comment: iam thinking to use inverse image of a closed set under a continuos function is closed , but here 2 x^2 cos(1/x)  is continuos on R/{0} ,since not define at x=0 ,on the set A=[-infinity , 1]  is closed  , f(x) is not continuos (due to zero ) .

Comment: P={x is in R such that 2 x^2 cos(1/x) >1} then here 2 x^2 cos(1/x)  is continuos , and (1, inifnity ) is open set so P is open set now P compliment is K={ x is in R such that 2 x^2 cos(1/x) <=1} is a closed set ?? and {0} is a closed set so , T=k U{0} is a closed set , Am i right ??? sorry for my english

Comment: Can you find upper and lower bounding functions?

Comment: Retracting downvote and close vote because you included effort in the comments. Please edit this in your post, or I can assure you your post will be closed. If you edit it in your post using Mathjax/latex, I will also give an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, judging from the comment you made, but one of the sets you claim to be closed isn't (it's what you call $K$). No big deal, anyway: it can be fixed.

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x^2\cos\dfrac{1}{x} & x\ne0 \\[6px]
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
This function is clearly continuous at every $x\ne0$; on the other hand,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0
$$
because you can squeeze
$$
-2x^2\le2x^2\cos\frac{1}{x}\le 2x^2
$$
(for $x\ne0$).

Now $T=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)\le 1\}$, so…

Comment: I need help , you change the definition of f(x) , so it is not the same f(x) as in the question , f(x) is not definite at point x=0 , rest , i understand that the extension you made is continuos .

Comment: @user534210 And where’s the point? You want to show that a set is closed, every tool is allowed.